# styled-components ThemeProvider breaks in React Native => Expo Web build

Tags: expo, styled-components, react-native-web

I’m working with a small expo project setup where I develop for both iOS/Android and Web. I recently wanted to add styled-components to the project and got everything up and running for Web and Mobile until I started working with a Theme Provider and the theme prop. I am 99% certain that I should have done everything correctly because it works for mobile but I get a JS exception in the web version.

- I’ve created a type for the theme and I know it works because my IDE tells me when I try to add something wrong to the theme.
- I’ve created a theme.ts and import it in the component where I’ve implemented the ThemeProvider. I know this works because when accessing prop.theme I get auto-completion and as I said it works on mobile.

```
const Container = styled.View`
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.color.primary};
`
```

This is the error I get:
**TypeError: Cannot read property ‘primary’ of undefined**

I suspect it might have something to do with expo’s bundler and missing loaders or something? I don’t know. To my knowledge, I did everything as in the docs and suspect it is an issue with Expo Web and the ThemeProvider.

Those are the relevant packages I'm using:

```
"expo": "~39.0.2"
"styled-components": "^5.2.1"
"@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
```

I'm blocked by this because I need to decide whether to proceed with styled components or without them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that when you import the ThemeProvider from "styled-components" and then work with "styled-components/native" that iOS and Android builds still work but web breaks...

This was my error. Use "styled-components/native" everywhere!
Stupid me

Answer (score 0):

lol... same. One thing I recommend is creating a lint rule for proper import for anyone who wants to avoid repeating this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).